# Metadata for each frame of a video

Tags: python, intel, realsense

I'm working on an embedded system project using Python to get video streams from 3 cameras. One main goal of the project is to get not only each frame of the cameras but to also get related metadata (timestamps, resolution, FPS ...) and send them to a server PC.

I've managed to get a good part of the system functioning but can't figure out a way to stack/save/edit metadata on a frame of the video.

I've found a very interesting tool that is 'exif' of Python but cannot go further with it as it is only applicable on a photo and not on a video (multiple frames).

Does anyone have any ideas or possible solutions for this ?
Thanks a lot,